# WCAG 2.0 A (1.3.1) Content outside of landmarks

Tags: wai-aria, wcag2.0

Trying to make our SharePoint site WCAG compliant. I have added WAI-ARIA landmarks to the real content, but it is not passing because not all content is included.

> When using HTML5 or WAI-ARIA landmarks it is best practice to include
>   all content on the page in landmarks. In this way users of assistive
>   technologies can use the landmarks for navigating the page without
>   losing track of content.
>
> Make sure that all content on the page is included in HTML5 or
>   WAI-ARIA landmarks.

The issue is that the things that are coming back as errors are things I would not want to alert screen readers to like Googele Tag Manager:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=XYZ" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

And random SP generated code like:

```
<div style="display:none" id="hidZone"><menu class="ms-hide"><ie:menuitem id="MSOMenu_Help" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/HelpIcon.gif" onmenuclick="MSOWebPartPage_S`enter code here`etNewWindowLocation(MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpLink'),`enter code here`MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpMode'))" text="Help" type="option" style="display:none"></ie:menuitem></menu></div>
```

Should I ignore these since it is not "real" content? Not sure what is the real best practice here.

Comment: where did the citation come from?  "make sure that all content on the page is included in landmarks"?  that is not a wcag requirement.

Comment: I believe that's from Axe, see https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/region?application=axeAPI. But you're right, it's not part of WCAG but considered 'best practice' really to allow users to easily skip straight to the relevant sections or content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

[**1.3.1 Info and Relationships**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#content-structure-separation-programmatic):

> Information, structure, and relationships conveyed through presentation can be programmatically determined or are available in text.

If you don’t *present* it (visually, auditory, …), you don’t have to care.

So your two examples, which seem not to be intended to be perceived by your users, are not affected by 1.3.1.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured, just needed to hear someone else say it too.